# ordering by match accuracy in t-sql using multiple where-like statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am building a query such as this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE field like '%a%'
OR field like '%b%'
OR field like '%c'
```

I'd like to tag on an `ORDER BY` clause that orders by the amount of matches found--something along the lines of making some extra column in the result set that increments if `a`, `b` or `c` was found in the field and then order by that number.

is this possible without creating some kind of temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into full text indexing if this table is at all large but a query without.

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  field like '%a%'
        OR field like '%b%'
        OR field like '%c'
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN field like '%a%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END + CASE
                  WHEN field like '%b%' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END + CASE
                        WHEN field like '%c%' THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                      END
```